# How to store multiple values (more than 2) in a map from a ResultSet, similar to HashMap?

Tags: java, sql, database, hashmap, resultset

I am new java and to this website and have never asked a question on here before.

My question is, I am trying to write a method that will query the database and this query returns 7 columns of data with 'X' amount of rows and one primary key.  I know that with HashMap you can store two values, key and value, but is it possible to take a ResultSet with more than two values per row and store it in a HashMap or something similar.  I have been struggling to find an answer to this on the internet.

I am trying to use this method as a cache so that the application does not have to query the database every time it needs information.  But I want to store the information so that when the user searches for the key value (ex. customerId), I get the 6 columns of information associated with that 'customerId' and the application simply gets it from the "map" rather than querying the database every time.

Any suggestions would be helpful and I am sorry if this question is a repeat.  It seems to happen often on here but I was unable to find an answer.

Comment: If you're spending a lot of time unpacking databases queries into a form you can use, you should look into [ORM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067860/what-is-object-relational-mappingorm-in-relation-to-hibernate-and-jdbc)s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can encapsulate them in a class, for example:

```
public Class EncapsulatedVariables {
    String s;
    int i;
    boolean b;
    public EncapsulatedVariables(String s, int i, boolean b) {
        this.s = s;
        this.i = i;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

Then you can use an instance of this class as the value in a `HashMap`, and have methods to retrieve and/or process the data as you deem fit.

Answer (score 0):

Create a customer class to store your values. As you iterate over your resultset, initialize a new customer for every record and place the object into a hashmap using the customerid as the key. Your map would be initalized as `Map<String,Customer> cache = new HashMap<String,Customer>();`