# Transpose result of hibernate query into list of POJOs

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I got a generics class that contains runQuery method that has following code setup:

```
public Object runQuery(String query) {

       Query retVal = getSession().createSQLQuery(query);


     return retVal.list();
   }
```

I am trying to figure out how to transpose the returned values into a list of Check objects (List):

```
public class Check {
  private int id;
  private String name;
  private String confirmationId;

//getters and setters
    }
```

Most queries that i run are actually stored procs in mysql. I know of native queries and resultTransforms (which if implemented would mean i have to change my generics and not after that).
Any ideas how i can accomplish this with current setup?

Comment: I belive you're trying to use hibernate as an ORM, there are tons of tutorials on this on the internet: http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/hibernate-tutorials/ (I would suggest using annotation rather than xml mapping)

Comment: @Asoub tutorials on what exactly? can you point me to the one that solves the problem i have described?

Answer (score 0):

You can find tutorials on ORMs ( [What is Object/relational mapping(ORM) in relation to Hibernate and JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067860/what-is-object-relational-mappingorm-in-relation-to-hibernate-and-jdbc) ).

Basically, you add annotation to your Check class to tell hibernate which java fields matches which DB field, make a JPQL (it looks like SQL) request and it gets your object and maps them from DB to POJO.

It's a broad subject, this is a good start: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_quick_guide.htm 
It will require some configuration, but that's worth it. Here's one tutorial on annotation based configuration: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_annotations.htm but with less explanations on how ORM works (there's also EclipseLink as an ORM)

Else, you could make you're own mapper, which takes values from a `ResultSet`, and set them in your class. For a lot of reason, I would recommand using an ORM than this method (Except maybe if you have only one class that is stored in the DB, which I doubt).

Comment: Can you explain how your answer helps me achieve a transpose of retVal.list() into List<Check> from a stored proced call?

Comment: Once you've set up the hibernate ORM environnement, you'll use something like `List<Check> yourCheckList = getEntityManager().createQuery("Select c From Check where c.name=:yourNameParametr" , Check.class).setParameter("yourNameParameter", "todolist").getResultList();` With the configuration it automatically transform the JPQL result in a list of your class.

Comment: you need to re-read the question again, i don't need help setting up hibernate engine. I need to transpose list() returned values into List<Check>

Comment: journaldev.com/3422/hibernate-native-sql-query-example

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13954761)

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't. All it shows is a manual parsing setup which would need to be developed for every instance of transpose from object to pojo. As mentioned in question i have already investigated that potential, but hoping there is a simpler and a more ORM centric way so that i can integrate it into a generic class.

Comment: @Potame, as you can see, it still doesn't answer the question. I have already stated my answer (which isn't exactly what OP needs, I'm just helping him now, so I'm not really elaborating, feel free to downvote or add an answer once it's ok). Now I think the `Transformers.aliasToBean()` might be of interest to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445092/hibernate-aliastobean